# Is there evidence to suggest that one's epistemic preference is fixed or is flexible?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, cognitive-neuroscience

We know that there are [methods of obtaining knowledge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_obtaining_knowledge#Methods). These being:

- Observation or experience.
- Reason or Logic
- Modelling
- Testimony.
- Authority.
- Truth by message.

Some call this [epistemic preference](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/39286/4472).

I wondering if this can be influenced to change - if people wilfully choose it, if it is a factor of their upbringing or is even genetic.

My question is: **Is there evidence to suggest that one's epistemic preference is fixed or is flexible?**

Comment: Interesting question! The science behind scientists. How meta.